# how to set the laravel sanctum settings correctly to work with SPA?

Tags: php, laravel, cors, single-page-application, session-cookies

I am building a simple Laravel API using sanctum. I made a login endpoint inside **api.php**:

```
Route::post('/login', [ApiController::class, 'login']);
```

and it is intended to send **access_token** as a cookie at successful authentication, and it works; here's the code:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if (!Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {

            return response()->json([
                "success" => false,
                "message" => "These credentials do not match our records"
            ], 401);
        }

        $token = Auth::user()->createToken('*sometoken*')->plainTextToken;
 

        return response()->json(["success" => true])->withCookie(cookie('access_token', $token, 60));
    }
```

now I have another simple endpoint, that should be protected with this authentication; i.e; I should send the cookie in the request for it to work.

```
Route::get('user-data', function() {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'it works!']);
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');
```

but in postman, it returns 500 error and sometimes and I get this error in the laravel terminal:

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)

My relevant settings in **.env**:

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost
SESSION_DOMAIN=*
```

in **cors.php**:

```
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

in **sanctum.php**:

```php
    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),

    'guard' => ['api'],

    'expiration' => null,

    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Could you please check `storage/logs/laravel.log` in order to provide more information about your error?

Comment: You should add the port number of your client to SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS and SESSION_DOMAIN should be localhost.